# Django 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I'm new to Django and I created function to allow admin to create users accounts. I used a password generator + make_password() function to hash the password.

Now it's sending the plain password to users email and storing it in the database hashed, I used check_password() to compare but I'm getting this error:
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'startswith'

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_email = request.POST['user_email']
        user_password = request.POST['user_password']
        user_details = User.objects.filter(user_email=user_email).values()
        hashed_pw = User.objects.filter(user_password=user_password).values()
        check_password(user_password, hashed_pw)

        if user_details:
            request.session['logged_in'] = True
            request.session['user_email'] = user_details[0]["user_email"]
            request.session['u_id'] = user_details[0]["user_email"]
            request.session['user_name'] = user_details[0]["user_name"]
            request.session['u_type'] = "emp"
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_index')
        else:
            return render(request, 'EmpLogin.html', {'msg': "0"})
    else:
        return render(request, 'EmpLogin.html')
```

User model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_email = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    user_role_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user_password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user_avatar_path = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    user_job_title = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    user_educ_qual = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    user_companies = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user'
```

Comment: You seem to be reinventing the wheel there with the way you are storing your users information in the session. Have a look at the documentation on: [Using the Django authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_email = request.POST['user_email']
        user_password = request.POST['user_password']
        user_details = User.objects.filter(user_email=user_email).first()

        if user_details and check_password(user_password, user_details.user_password):
            request.session['logged_in'] = True
            request.session['user_email'] = user_details.user_email
            request.session['u_id'] = user_details.user_email
            request.session['user_name'] = user_details.user_name
            request.session['u_type'] = "emp"
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_index')
        else:
            return render(request, 'EmpLogin.html', {'msg': "0"})
    else:
        return render(request, 'EmpLogin.html')
```

Comment: it's returning false

Comment: @JHS99, `user = User.objects.filter(user_email=user_email).first()`   `print(user)`  what you get from here?

Comment: User object (norahhamad98@outlook.com)

Comment: @JHS99 Please check the updated code from the answer. Now I am checking password in a two way.  Please check it . Is it working for you?

Comment: Works! thanks a lot I appreciate the help. can you please explain so I understand what did you change for it to work?

Comment: @JHS99, You know  check_password() function should be passed the plain-text password as the first argument, and the hashed password as the second argument. Also, I removed the values() method from the User.objects.filter(user_password=user_password) query, as it is not needed for this code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

check_password is the User model's method. To call the django check_password method you need the user object.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.check_password

> check_password(raw_password)¶
> Returns True if the given raw string is the correct password for the user. (This takes care of the password hashing in making the comparison.)

try this

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_email = request.POST['user_email']
        user_password = request.POST['user_password']
        user_details = User.objects.filter(user_email=user_email).values()
        hashed_pw = User.objects.filter(user_password=user_password).values()
        
        user_object = User.objects.filter(user_email=user_email).last()  # getting the user using email id
        if user_object:
            is_password_valid = user_object.check_password(user_password)  # checking the user's password
            print(is_password_valid)

        if user_details:
            request.session['logged_in'] = True
            request.session['user_email'] = user_details[0]["user_email"]
            request.session['u_id'] = user_details[0]["user_email"]
            request.session['user_name'] = user_details[0]["user_name"]
            request.session['u_type'] = "emp"
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_index')
        else:
            return render(request, 'EmpLogin.html', {'msg': "0"})
    else:
        return render(request, 'EmpLogin.html')
```

Comment: thanks! I'm getting 'User' object has no attribute 'check_password'

Comment: @JHS99 that's because you aren't using Django's builtin authentication system. See: [Customizing authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/) if the default implementation is not suitable for you.